# routing of static website using nodeJs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, routes

I build a website using angular js. But That is not a SPA. I use angular js for API calling and fetch some data only so now I want to do routing for custom URL of my HTML pages how will I do it ? I am serving my website using nodeJs. is there any configuration in node js to set custom URL of static website/routing.

Comment: Can you explain the requirement in detail, I may be able to help if I get a better understanding of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

For using the routes in nodejs you can use express.Router() module.It can be installed same as express and then you can define the routes on that.
For example :-

```
     var adminRouter = express.Router();
     adminRouter.get('/',function(req,res){
         res.send('Here is the dashboard for my app');
     });
     adminRouter.get('/users',function(req,res){
         res.send('Here is the menu to show all the users');
     });

     //Now to apply the routes to your app

     app.use('/admin',adminRouter);
```

You can also route the middleware of your app and the url parameters separately